# Hello I'm trying to do this function in variable

Tags: ios, swift

```
let fun:() -> () = func function() -> (){
    print("Hello Function")
}
fun()
```

error: consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you'd do it in Swift with [closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html):

```
let fun:() -> () = {
    print("Hello Function")
}
fun()
```

Or you can do it this way:

```
func function() {
    print("Hello Function")
}
let fun:(() -> ()) = function

fun()
```

Comment: Ya I know that, But I want to add function instead of closure as per my requirement

Comment: did the second way helped @RaviPatel ?

Comment: Yes... Thanks @denis_Ior